# XCODE stack viewについて

Tags: xcode

xcodeのバージョンが9.2で,3つのイメージを一つのグループにしたいのですが(レイアウトの為)

3つのイメージをクリックして選択し,alineボタンの左のstackボタンを押すと一つのグループにまとまるのですが

UIStackView before iOS 9.0 (iOS 9.0より前のUIStackView) 
というメッセージが出てエラーになります。

Comment: Deployment Targetの設定 9.0 で解決しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIStackView`はiOS9以降で使うことができます。
何かしらの設定がiOS9より前になっているためエラーがでています。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758808/uistackview-before-ios-9-0

を参考に各種設定を見直してみるとよいと思います。

具体的には

`Project Targets-> Deployment info -> Deployment Target`
や
ストリーボードやxibの`Builds for`
です。

もちろん、設定を変更すればアプリ全体もしくは一部がiOS9以降のみのサポートとなります。